# Can't sync calendar on my BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, calendar

I can't sync my google calender anymore with core app calender. It did sync before. When I try to sync it, comes notification bubble saying "fail to sync". Contacts and Gmail syncs OK.
I tried to remove google account from phone and readded it. Didin't help.
Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-calendar-app/+bug/1439554 Sadly nothing has been said about a fix yet. So this is a general problem and has nothing to do with your end.